# SUBQUERY WITH SAME TABLE

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a table that contains :

- ID_Magasin: 001 for wharehouse, c01 for a magasin1, c02 for magasin 2, ..
- Qte_Physique: the quantity number of an article
- id_article: code article
- lib_article: article designation

I want a query first, bring all the quantity of articles for each magasin.
second, in the same query I want to add a new column to display the quantity of the same article in the datawherhouse.

Comment: Have you tried writing query yourself yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: please share the sample code which you have tried.

Comment: SELECT GQ_DEPOT,GQ_ARTICLE,GQ_PHYSIQUE,
(
SELECT GQ_PHYSIQUE AS WH_PHYSIQUE FROM DISPO WHERE GQ_DEPOT =('001')
)
FROM DISPO

Comment: Desired results would help.

Comment: What is the table's key? Is `id_magasin` + `id_article` unique or can there be multiple entries for a `id_magasin` + `id_article`?

Comment: Please always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. Which is it? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: table keys : ID_magasins and ID_article

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a window function:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*, 
            sum(case when id_magasin = '001' then Qte_Physique else 0 end) over (partition by id_article) as wharehouse_qte
     from dispo d
    ) d
where id_magasin <> '001';
```

Comment: Thank's for your proposition. But all the wharehouse_qte values return 0.

Comment: I can't follow the logic here. The outer query filters out rows with `id_magasin` equal to 001, then we aggregate values but only for those rows where `id_magasin` *does* equal 001.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is not correlated to the main query. I.e. it is lacking the condition which product to look at.

```
select
  gq_depot,
  gq_article,
  gq_physique,
  (
    select warehouse.gq_physique
    from dispo warehouse
    where warehouse.gq_depot = '001'
    and warehouse.gq_article = magasin.gq_article
  ) as wh_physique
from dispo magasin
where gq_depot <> '001'
order by gq_depot, gq_article;
```

You can do the same with a join:

```
select
  magasin.gq_depot,
  magasin.gq_article,
  magasin.gq_physique,
  warehouse.gq_physique as wh_physique
from dispo magasin
left join dispo warehouse on  warehouse.gq_article = magasin.gq_article
                          and warehouse.gq_depot = '001'
where magasin.gq_depot <> '001'
order by magasin.gq_depot, magasin.gq_article;
```

For readability you may use `WITH` clauses, if your DBMS features them:

```
with warehouse as (select * from dispo where gq_depot = '001')
   , magasin as (select * from dispo where gq_depot <> '001')
select
  magasin.gq_depot,
  magasin.gq_article,
  magasin.gq_physique,
  warehouse.gq_physique as wh_physique
from magasin
left join warehouse on warehouse.gq_article = magasin.gq_article
order by magasin.gq_depot, magasin.gq_article;
```

Above queries only work correctly, if `gq_depot` + `gq_article` are unique in the table (e.g. constituting the primary key). Otherwise you'd need aggregation to get total `gq_physique` per `gq_depot` + `gq_article`.